# Can PHP write SOAP function base on sample XML file?

Tags: php, soap

I have a sample XML file which connect to SOAP server and  set "Tier" attribute of "usero1" to "pkg01".

When run this XML file on SOAP UI, it work.

and I want to create a SOAP function for this job via PHP. But I don't know how to start, and how many function I have to call? Any one please help.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ws="http://ws.subscriberservices.sandvine.com">
   <soapenv:Header xmlns:svsec="http://services.sandvine.com">
      <svsec:username>username</svsec:username>
      <svsec:password>password</svsec:password>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ws:SetSubscriberAttributesRequest>
         <Debug>false</Debug>
         <BulkOperationFailureBehaviour>AllOrNothing</BulkOperationFailureBehaviour>
         <SetSubscriberAttributeParameterSets>
            <SetSubscriberAttributeParameterSet>
               <SubscriberKey>
                  <SubscriberRealmKey>
                     <Name>DEFAULT</Name>
                  </SubscriberRealmKey>
                  <Name>user01</Name>
               </SubscriberKey>
               <SubscriberAttributeDefinitionKey>
                  <Name>Tier</Name>
               </SubscriberAttributeDefinitionKey>
               <Value>pkg01</Value>
            </SetSubscriberAttributeParameterSet>
        </SetSubscriberAttributeParameterSets>
         <ResponseGroups>
            <ResponseGroup>Subscriber.Shallow</ResponseGroup>
         </ResponseGroups>
      </ws:SetSubscriberAttributesRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Could you please let me know in detail? I'm very new to SOAP, I don't know how many function to call? and how to pass parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XML file is not connecting to the SOAP server - the XML file represents a SOAP request.

What you will need to do is write a php SOAP client for your SOAP server. For this you will need:

1. The uri of the wsdl file for the SOAP server (this is essentially metadata that allows your client to create requests - it describes the functionality the server allows)
2. Zend_Soap_Client classes - http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.soap.client.html

You can read up more on PHP and SOAP here [Implement SOAP services with the Zend Framework](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/x-zsoap/index.html)

Comment: Yes, XML code is a request but when put this XML code in SOAP UI, it can conect to server like client request it. I have to write PHP code but I don't know what function to call, Can I check function base on XML file? How many function I have to call?

Comment: This is sample screen from SOAP UI which work, https://dl.dropbox.com/u/67227764/sandvine/SetSubscriberAttributes%20Request%201-1.jpg

Comment: You can figure out what functions to call, if you have the wsdl file. From the XML I am guessing the endpoint is SetSubscriberAttributesRequest.

Comment: Since it has this tag, <SetSubscriberAttributeParameterSets> I'm not sure do I still need to call this function also, How can I really check ?

Comment: I'm guessing everything else nested under SetSubscriberAttributeParameterSets are parameters - or it could be a callback. Is this something internal, or is this a third party system with documentation online?

Comment: I just checked that <SetSubscriberAttributeParameterSets>  is parameter of SetSubscriberAttributesRequest. What I don't know is how can I pass username and password for authentication ? an how can I pass parameter for function SetSubscriberAttributeRequest ?

Comment: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/67227764/sandvine/01.png and https://dl.dropbox.com/u/67227764/sandvine/02.png

Comment: From the xml you have above - You would pass the username and password for authentication in the header. In code, these would just be key - value pairs.

Comment: Do you mean I can put the XML header code in PHP script? and replace with correct username and pass? Or any special function to put authentication ?